# std::array copy construction using braces

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, list-initialization

Why doesn't the following code compile:

```
#include <array>

struct A
{
    std::array<size_t, 5> i_;

    A() {}

    A( A const& a)
    : i_{ a.i_ } {}
};

int main()
{
    A a1;
    A a2 = a1;

    return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.8.1 says

error: cannot convert 'const std::array' to 'long unsigned int' in initialization
: i_{ a.i_ }

Comment: Braces are for elements with `std::array`. The entire array isn't an element. You don't even need to explicitly define that copy constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `std::array` is an aggregate, hence you can not use curly brackets to call the copy-ctor. You would need to specify the elements. This also explains your error message, it is trying to convert the `a.i_` to an element of the array, which is a `size_t`. Since you can not do that, you *must* use `i_(a.i_)` to create a copy.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
A( A const& a )
: i_( a.i_ ) {}
```

Comment: I thought that in C++11 braces provide uniform syntax and changing () to {} should not cause compilation to fail. Also why is the error message so strange, why does it try to convert to `size_t`?